# Does the compactness of two compact set require the Hausdorff separation axiom on the TVS? Same for connectedness

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, connectedness

I study Functional Analysis and a little bit of Topology. I am currently trying to prove that the sum of two compact sets is compact in a separated TVS.
Let $E$ be a separated TVS and $A,B \subset E$ two compacts subsets.
We know that the map $$\begin{align*}f:\space&E \times E\rightarrow E\\&(x,y)\mapsto x+y\end{align*}$$ is continuous and that $A\times B$ is compact in $E\times E$.
The image of a compact set by a continuous map is compact. Thus the compactness of $A+B$.
My questions are:

- In this proof, what is the use of $E$ being separated?
- What about connectedness of the sum of two connected subsets?

Comment: Continuous image of a compact set is compact and continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, does that require E being a Hausdorff space?

Comment: No, it does  not require Hausdorff property.

Comment: What is a "separated" TVS???